# Establishing attribute order in table using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, arcgis-pro, sorting

I have the following piece of code hoping to have a table with a set of fields on a specific order:

```
#Removing the fields we do NOT want to show in the output
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_target_output_1, 'fl_target_output_1')
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc_target_output_1)]
keep_fields = ['OBJECTID','Shape','LOCATION','LENGTH','ESTATE','DISTANCE','STATUS','CONNECTION']
i = len(keep_fields)
for j in range (i):
    aux = keep_fields[j]
    fields.remove(aux)
arcpy.DeleteField_management ('fl_target_output_1', fields)

#Sorting output by distance
fc_target_output_2 = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Temp.gdb\target_output_2'
arcpy.Sort_management('fl_target_output_1', fc_target_output_2, [['LENGTH', 'ASCENDING']])
```

However, when I open 'fc_target_output_2' the attributes appear in any random order and not as I listed them in 'keep_fields'. They don't even appear in the order they initially were in 'fc_target_output_1'.

Any ideas on how to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: The Q&As near the top of this list should give you some ideas: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=re-order+fields+is%3Aquestion  They are for ArcGIS Desktop rather than ArcGIS Pro but I think will still apply.

Comment: Where is data source `fc_target_output_1` stored? (file geodatabase, shapefile, enterprise geodatabase, etc).  Can you include print statements for your ListFields to show us their order at the beginning and end of your code snippet?

Comment: fc_target_output_1 is a feature class in a file geodatabase.

I have actually tried using MakeQueryTable_management, but I can't get it to work. I get an error (no details about it).


#arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management(['fl_target_output_2'], ['fl_target_output_3'], 'NO_KEY_FIELD', "", [['fl_target_output_2.LOCATION', 'Location'],['fl_target_output_2.ESTATE', 'Estate'],['fl_target_output_2.DISTANCE', 'Distance'],['fl_target_output_2.STATUS', 'Status'],['fl_target_output_2.CONNECTION', 'Connected To']])

Comment: If you cannot get MakeQueryTable to work then a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) that uses that would make the basis for a new question.

Comment: Since your question appears to be about the order of fields (columns) in a table rather than about the order of rows (features) in that table I think you should remove the code for "Sorting output by distance" from the snippet that you present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Temp.gdb'
#Removing the fields we do NOT want to show in the output
mylayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_target_output_1, 'fl_target_output_1')
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(mylayer)]
keep_fields = ['OBJECTID','Shape','LOCATION','LENGTH','ESTATE','DISTANCE','STATUS','CONNECTION']
i = len(keep_fields)
for j in range (i):
    aux = keep_fields[j]
    fields.remove(aux)
arcpy.DeleteField_management (mylayer, fields)

#Sorting output by distance
arcpy.Sort_management(mylayer, 'target_output_2', [['LENGTH', 'ASCENDING']])
```

Comment: Doesn't this just leave any fields that are not deleted in their original sort order?

Comment: @PolyGeo  Thanks for your attention. You are right. But the asker said it's a piece of code. So i  don't know what's the processing of the full code. just tried to edit and correct this code without any big change of the main body.

Comment: I can't really see any significant difference with the original code apart from the the fact that feature layer 'fl_target_output_1' is saved into a variable called 'mylayer'. Also, the second parameter of Sort_management needs to be a feature class (you seem to have changed it for a feature layer), right? When I run your code it throws an error on that line. Please, let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @PitrakoJunior The second parameter of sort_managemet is a feature class saved in Optimity_Temp.gdb if you set arcpy.en.workspace to it. What's your error?